# spring-boot produce a web service : how to change the input and output class name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ws

I am using spring-boot to produce a web service
but I would like to use as input and output class something like requestBean and responseBean

I have the impression that spring-boot wants to have input and output classes like XXXRequest and XXXResponse

Regards Franck

Comment: welcome to the community. Please elaborate your query

Comment: i am following the example https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/... Now I would like to change the input and output classes. In the example they are GetCountryRequest and GetCountryResponse. I would like to name them RequestBean and ResponseBean.

Comment: Again, please elaborate

Comment: in the example https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/ in the file countries.xsd, the elements must finish by Request or Response. How can I have something different  ?